# Content search does not work (18.10)

Tags: nautilus, 18.10, search, tracker, indexing

LS,
Searching my document on content is not working at all on my system.

This is what I've done:
I installed Tracker. And let it index.
The status says it's done. The amount of files it indexed is the same as the amount of files I think I have.
Search in Nautilus, `Tracker search` and this screen you when when hitting the *super key*.

I also followed most of the thread described in [Bug #1767817](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1767817). Here is says a fix is released, might this be for 19.04. I'm using the most updated version of Ubuntu (I assume), still does not work.
Quite some reported that search in Tracker did work but not in Nautilus, for me it does not work anywhere.

Using Tracker seems to be the most suitable way for searching files by content. I like to keep Ubuntu as pristine as possible.

Any suggestions?

PS I'm a bit of a n00p in Linux so it might be that I don know what I'm talkin about.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the bug description, we can see that the Ubuntu dev team has released a proposed update of Nautilus for 18.04. (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1767817)

If you want to test it, you should enable the 'proposed updates' source in `software-properties-gtk` app, at developer tab.

Tested with Cosmic (18.10), it works but Nautilus gets quite unstable.

Comment: Thank you @cmak.fr.
I did added the pre-released updates (cosmic-proposed)
After update, reboot and hard reset en re-index of tracker searches with content in Nautilus works. So thank you! Everything seems stable.

Comment: Sorry the enter button is really sensitive. This is what I wanted to comment:

Thank you @cmak.fr. for you suggestion.
I did added the pre-released updates (cosmic-proposed)
After update, reboot and hard reset en re-index of tracker searches with content in Nautilus works. So thank you! Everything seems stable.
Search with `Tracker search` still doesn't work. Maybe I'm using that wrong: `tracker search <string>` gives Results: [emptiness].

Comment: See the help `tracker help search` - And try this `tracker search -a '*part-of-a-word*'`

Comment: OK it now works. BUT not with numbers.  
Is this normal for Tracker? What I use it the most for is searching in large databases of orders (pdf files), I need to search on order number.  
Any suggestions for that?